# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in Spring (3.0.5.RELEASE)

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to use this class but I can't seem to figure out how to limit the rows returned. Plain JdbcTemplate has a max row and max fetch size setter. Is there any way to get similar functionality out of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` exposes its underlying `JdbcTemplate` via `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations()`:

```
((JdbcTemplate) namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations()).setMaxRows(...);
```

Just for information: note that `setMaxRows()` shouldn't be used to set limits for individual queries (because `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` is intended to be thread-safe, so that you shouldn't change its state after it have been initialized). Limits for individual queries are usually set by appropriate SQL clauses.